# force iframe to inner content height

Tags: iframe

I am trying to force an iframe to the exact same height as the inner content i have tried so many different solution is it even possible i think the issue maybe because the inner playlist doesn't load straight away.

here is an example
http://jsfiddle.net/isimpledesign/ESrCZ/

```
<iframe width="400" height="100%" src="http://s3fileshare.com/wp-playlist/?bucket=isdrandom&email=info@isimpledesign.co.uk"  onLoad="calcHeight();" frameborder="1" id="resize" name="resize"></iframe>​
```

Can someone advise me on a way to do this???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error that you'll see in the javascript console, resulting in your function not getting called.

However this isn't going to work anyway.  You're going to run into the cross domain iframe sizing problem (due to same origin policy).

If you have control over both domains, you can check into solutions such as this:

http://css-tricks.com/cross-domain-iframe-resizing/